# Create Redis instance with Azure along with Redis Configuration JSON file throwing error

Tags: azure, redis, azure-cli

I am currently attempting to create a redis cache for azure via the cli using the typical example

```
az redis create --location westus2 --name MyRedisCache --resource-group MyResourceGroup --sku Basic --vm-size c0
```

However, what I'd love to do is use the ----redis-configuration add-on to tell redis I do NOT want to deal with security via the                     "requirepass" : " property

No matter how I try to add this property, I'm given an error.

Has anyone successfully used --redis-configuration to pass in additional requirements for the deployment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering `Azure Redis` is a fully managed service where Microsoft creates and manages the Redis instance(s) (updates, automatic failover etc.) on behalf of the customer, not all configuration settings (like `requirepass`) are exposed to users.

Looking at the REST API documentation for [`creating an Azure Redis instance`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/redis/redis/create), few configuration settings that can be changed are:

> rdb-backup-enabled,rdb-storage-connection-string,rdb-backup-frequency,maxmemory-delta,maxmemory-policy,notify-keyspace-events,maxmemory-samples,slowlog-log-slower-than,slowlog-max-len,list-max-ziplist-entries,list-max-ziplist-value,hash-max-ziplist-entries,hash-max-ziplist-value,set-max-intset-entries,zset-max-ziplist-entries,zset-max-ziplist-value
>   etc.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of